# Python Crawler - Check to see if a javascript line exists and if so, parse it

Tags: python

I am scraping a page in python 2.7 using lxml.html and I need to do the following...

1) find out if this line is on the page.  I am actually looking to see if parent_asin exists.  Its not on every page.

```
DetailPage.StateController.setState('parent_asin', 'B0000DB87U');
```

2) If it does exist, the how to I get B0000DB87U?  That will change for every page when parent_asin is in the page.  This is all in javascript and I am using lxml to fetch and parse html.  Need another approach for JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lxml to extract all the content of `<script>` tag, then parse them with regex.

Untested example:

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(url)
scripts = doc.xpath('//script')
for script in scripts:
    match = re.findall(r"DetailPage\.StateController\.setState\('parent_asin', '(.*)'\);", script.text)
    if match:
        print match[0]
```